# Using `printf` to print variable containing `%` percent sign results in "bash: printf: `p': invalid format character"

Tags: bash, variable, echo, escape-characters, printf

I want to use `printf` to print a variable. It might be possible that this variable contains a `%` percent sign.

Minimal example:

```
$ TEST="contains % percent"
$ echo "${TEST}"
contains % percent
$ printf "${TEST}\n"
bash: printf: `p': invalid format character
contains $
```

(`echo` provides the desired output.)

Comment: The docs are pretty clear that the first parameter is supposed to be a format string.

Comment: Not sure why some people need to downvote this. A lot of newcomers will make that mistake, so imo it's a very valuable question.

Comment: I have %variables% in my browser like %OS% and %VERSION%. How to print those?

Comment: You want print, not printf.  I made the same mistake.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `printf` in its normal form:

```
printf '%s\n' "${TEST}"
```

From `man printf`:

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
> printf FORMAT [ARGUMENT]...
> ```

---

You should **never** pass a variable to the FORMAT string as it may lead to errors and security vulnerabilities.

---

Btw:

if you want to have `%` sign as part of the FORMAT, you need to enter `%%`, e.g.:

```
$ printf '%d%%\n' 100
100%
```

Comment: Do you really need `"${TEST}"`, can't it be `"$TEST"`?

Comment: `"$TEST"` is enough.

Comment: +1. But it's not just 'normal', it's necessary. Passing a variable to printf's first parameter is Christmas to hackers. Never do it. That is part of secure software dev 101.

Comment: @Jeffrey Most of the potential vulnerabilities in printf are only applicable to the C function. There aren't as many evil things you can do by passing a bad format string to `/usr/bin/printf` (or the equivalent shell builtin).

Comment: @duskwuff you can do variable assignment using bash's `printf`, and variable assignments can lead to a lot more (e.g., shellshock in days past)

Comment: @Jeffrey, true, my answer was not clear enough about that I think. I added a sentence to emphasize that.

Comment: Why is it then allowed in the syntax to pass a variable to the format?

Comment: The variable substitution is  performed by bash, before `printf` is executed, so it cannot know of it.

Answer (score 13):

You should never put variable content in the format string given to `printf`. Use this instead:

```
printf '%s\n' "${TEST}"
```

Answer (score 5):

`printf` takes one guaranteed parameter, and then a number of additional parameters based on what you pass.  So something like this:

```bsh
printf '%07.2f' 5
```

gets turned into:

```
0005.00
```

The first parameter, called "`format`", is always present.  If it contains no `%`strings, it's simply printed.  Thus:

```bsh
printf Hello
```

produces simply `Hello` (notably, without the trailing newline `echo` would add in its default mode).  In expecting your example to work, you have been misled by your own previous (unknowing) abuse of this fact; because you only passed strings without `%`s into `format`, from `printf`'s point of view, you kept asking it to output things that required no substitutions, so it pretty much functioned like `echo -ne`.

If you want to do this *right*, you probably want to start forming your printable strings with `printf`'s builtin substitution capabilities.  Lines like this appear all over my code:

```bsh
printf '%20s: %6d %05d.%02d%%' "$key" $val $((val/max)) $((val*100/max%100))
```

If you want exactly what you're currently doing now to work, you want `echo -ne`, as so:

```bsh
TEST="contains % percent"
echo -ne "${TEST}\n"
```

That preserves the (questionable) behavior of interpreting `\` escapes inside the variable.  It also seems a little silly to supply `-n` and then stick the `\n` back on, but I offer it because it's a global find-and-replace you can apply to everything you're current doing.  A cleaner version that still keeps `\` escapes working in the variable would be:

```bsh
TEST="contains % percent"
echo -e "$TEST"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. As it actually has a working fix. The accepted answer talks about passing variables. But it is clear that there is no intention to pass variables, just the string has a % sign.  which in my case I have no control over.