# Colouring a bash print statement

Tags: bash, colors

I have the following bash print statement which I want to colour blue.

```
local -r sgr="$( tput sgr0 )"
local -r wht="$( tput bold; tput setaf 15 )"
local -r blu="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"

printf ' \u2263  %-*s%*s  \u2263\n'  "$cl" "${1:0:cl}"  "$cr" "${2:0:cr}"
```

Comment: Just prefix it with `"$blu"`.

Comment: The behaviour becomes different whether the format statement in enclosed by single or double quotes.  What goes on using one or the other?

Comment: Single quotes don't expand variables.

Comment: Add another `%s` and a `"$blu"` argument perhaps?

Comment: Just double quotes in the format string was enough.

Comment: The format string should _always_ be single-quoted. If you want variable data in your output from `printf`, insert a format specifier in the format string (e.g. `%s`) and supply the variable (`"$blu"`) as the argument corresponding that format string.

Comment: Why the insistence about single quotes?

Comment: See e.g. [Using \`printf\` to print variable containing \`%\` percent sign results in "bash: printf: \`p': invalid format character"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/519315)